# AJAX, Join Table and Complex Query

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I have two MySQL tables named 'nodes' and 'joinTable' like shown below.  I need to make an AJAX/jQuery?/MySQL call based on one node ID (in first table) that returns the following and pushes or places data into two JavaScript arrays and some variables:

1. returns 'type' and 'text' from
   Node table. These will be placed in
   a seperate variables along with id.
2. SELECT to_ FROM joinTable WHERE
   from_='$id' and then... goes through
   the nodes table to get all the
   associated  'type' and 'text' for
   each of the '_from' and places or 
   pushes these into a javascript array
   called 'pointsTo'  along with the
   nodeID.
3. SELECT from_ FROM
   joinTable WHERE to_='$id' and
   then... goes through the nodes table
   to get all the associated 'type' and
   'text' for each of the '_to' and
   places or pushes these into a
   javascript array called 'pointsFrom'
   along with the nodeID.

**nodes:**

```
nodeID    type  text  
0           1   Dr. Joelson  
1           1   Ms. Appletree 
2           1   Mr. Miller  
3           1   Dr. Wilson  
4           0   Pediatrician  
5           0   Teacher  
6           0   Waiter  
...
```

**joinTable:**

```
recordID    from_   to_   weight    type    typeText  
0              0    4        1        1      isa  
1              1    5        4        1      isa  
2              2    6        3        1      isa  
...
```

---

This AJAX options are overwelming to me and I have not done a MySQL call this 
complex before. I would not mind learning more about a jQuery methodology that is applicable but am open to different approaches.

---

Edit:
The server is running PHP.

Comment: Ah...I don't think Javascript can access MySQL. What is your web server running? PHP? JSP?

Comment: The server is running php. AJAX techniques access MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to start off by choosing a server-side language like PHP to query your database and send back a JSON response to the client.  On the other end, use a javascript framework like jQuery to make an ajax call to said PHP script on the server from your javascript code:

```
// Get your nodeId from the user
var id = 2;

$.post("/scripts/doTheQuery.php",{
  nodeId: id
},function (result) {
  // when query finishes
  // do stuff with result
  console.log(result);
}
```

As far as your SQL question:
1.
    `SELECT type,text FROM nodes WHERE nodeID = {$nodeIDinQuestion}`

I'll punt on the join queries and let you get that far first.

Comment: Thanks mikermcneil.  That is very similar to the basic setup I have - I have already parsed a string to get output on the page and a basic solution to question 1.  I appreciate this because it indicates I might be on the right path. ... I'm not really sure if parsing the string is the best (or only) approach. I need to look up 'JSON'.

Comment: JSON stands for Javascript Object Notation and is just an encoding for transfering data, like XML.  Instead of XML entities, you define javascript objects (with slightly more specific rules).  PHP has a class called encode_json that converts a PHP object or associative array into valid JSON.

Ex.
 { "success": true, "users": [ {"name":"mike"}, {"name","john"} ] }

Comment: Thanks again mikermcneil. I have my MySQL query delivered back to the page.  It was sent as a php array via 'json_encode(...)' and picked up in the page via jQuery's 'parseJSON'.  If I understand correctly, the subtle difference is while it can be accessed like an array, it is an object (e.g., object[3][1]).  Array functions like push,pop, length etc. won't work on it.  So I'm doing good but will research converting javascript object to javascript array.  Thanks again!